# IMCROP, zoom in, matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, zooming

I am using

[X,Y,I2,rect] = imcrop(…)
 function to get my sub-image.

1- I want first to zoom in my image and then crop my image. How it will work?

Using imtool i can first zoom in and then crop my image but i can export store rect coordinates.
regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supported out of the box: after you call IMCROP, a figure opens up with the image displayed. From the toolbar, use the pan/zoom tools as usual, once done disable them and you would be back to the mode where you specify the draggable rectangle. Make your selection and double-click it to accept.

Here is an example:

```
I = imread('coins.png');
[I2,rect] = imcrop(I);
figure, imshow(I2)
```

[image: pan-zoom-tools]
[image: crop]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to produce a new zoomed/cropped image, you can use `imresize` to enlarge the image before calling `imcrop`:

```
B = imresize(A, scale)
```

If instead you have the image displayed in Matlab and you want to zoom in on the figure programmatically, then you can use the `zoom` function:

```
zoom(factor)
```

See the documentation for details:

- `imresize` API: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imresize.html
- `zoom` API: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/zoom.html

Comment: @ Mansoor Siddiqui how can you use pan function / zoom out . Secondly I donot know scale to zoom in.

Comment: Are you trying to produce a new zoomed/cropped image?  Or are you just trying to get the image to show in Matlab, and have the ability zoom/pan?

Comment: I amended my solution to include the "zoom" function.